# Connect Tuxedo server via JCA/J2C using java/J2EE application in JBoss/Spring boot. Such as XMLink

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, jca, tuxedo

I am looking for the solution to implement the connectivity between web application (Java/J2ee) and existing Oracle Tuxedo service.

I have found few options such as XMLink, JOLT & etc.

How to configure in JBoss eas 6.x.x server / Spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to connect from wildlfy or jboss to an external information system (EIS) that is not JEE, is to write a resource adapter. A resource adapter act's as a driver to the EIS. If your EIS is a server, you need a outbound resource adapter. In this case your outbound resource adapter acts as client. If your EIS (Tuxeo) wants to access your Jboss-Server as a client, you need a inbound resource adapter. The inbound resource adapter acts as a server for external connections from an EIS.

The resource adapter jca framework in Wildfly is Ironjacamar. I think for Jboss too. The Ironjacamar framework has a codegenerator to generate an inbound or outbound resource adapter. I wrote a [simple sample project](https://github.com/joe-bookwood/inbound-ra-example) on Github and describe the usage of the codegenerator in this sample. I think it would run also on a Jboss Server. I hope that's help you.